# Organize Gaelyk Project

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gaelyk

I am working on a project using Groovy and Gaelyk. I want to organize my files in different folders inside of `/src/main/WEB-INF/groovy`.

It works when I put all files in the same folder, but not when I put them into different folders. Maybe changing the build config?

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please provide an example directory tree of your project, the contents of your `routes.groovy` and how you try to invoke it in the browser.

Comment: /src/main/WEB-INF/groovy  /controllers => my controllers  /datastores ==> my data objects    and my routes is like /login => /controllers/login.groovy

Answer (score 1):

When you put `.groovy` files in different directories you need to include the `package` declaration in the `.groovy` to match the directory structure.